# Why can't I upload ICO files to Wordpress?

Tags: favicon

Via the Site Identity settings in the Customizer, I can't upload a favicon image.  I get the error message 'Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.'

But if I just copy the favicon to my root directory via my Cpanel File Manager it works fine.  Why is Wordpress disallowing this?  Is there a security reason?

Comment: note that while I've left an answer, I did not try to enable `.ico` support in WP in my answer as you did not ask for it in your question. Instead I addressed the question that was asked and explained why. If you're asking how to enable `.ico` support you need to state it clearly and unambiguously as your question

Answer (score 4):

> Via the Site Identity settings in the Customizer, I can't upload a favicon image.

Site Identity != favicon image. It's used for favicons and resized down but it's also used in lots of other locations.

E.g. it can appear in:

- the theme header as the logo
- smartphone homescreens
- twitter and FB previews

So uploading a tiny image can be harmful, this is why the site identity has a minimum size recommendation. `.ico` files do not work in those places.

> I get the error message 'Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.'

Yes and no, WP does indeed support uploading of `.ico` files:

https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/functions.php#LL3350C5-L3351C5

```php
    return apply_filters(
        'mime_types',
        array(
            // Image formats.
            'jpg|jpeg|jpe'                 => 'image/jpeg',
            'gif'                          => 'image/gif',
            'png'                          => 'image/png',
            'bmp'                          => 'image/bmp',
            'tiff|tif'                     => 'image/tiff',
            'webp'                         => 'image/webp',
            'ico'                          => 'image/x-icon',
            'heic'                         => 'image/heic',
```

If you cannot then this means one of two things:

- a plugin or filter is removing support
- it's not a `.ico` at all but a different type of image masquerading as a `.ico` file! If you take a PNG file and rename it to a `.ico` most programs will recognise it as a PNG and still display it, even with the `.ico` extension, but it's still a PNG and its mimetype will not be `image/x-icon` leading WordPress to reject it
- the host is passing the file with the incorrect mime type

Eitherway you should be using PNG instead as it has wider support, fewer issues, and allows for higher resolutions, bit depths, and quality than `.ico` files.

The only benefit `.ico` has is that it has wider support on very old browsers.

> But if I just copy the favicon to my root directory via my Cpanel File Manager it works fine.

If no HTML tag tells the browser where to find the image for favicons, it requests `/favicon.ico` from the server as a fallback. Since you did not set a site identity image, WP doesn't print those HTML tags.

The browser is built to be very forgiving so even if it's not a valid `.ico` or if it's a PNG with a `.ico` extension it will still work when used this way.

> Why is Wordpress disallowing this? Is there a security reason?

WP allows it! But your server and the code in your theme/plugins does not. You will need to isolate this further by doing standard debugging steps such as disabling all plugins and using a default theme, then re-activating them one by one until the problem returns to identify the culprit.

#### But you shouldn't be using .ico favicons anyway

The site identity is used for far more than the favicon, and there's a reason WP wants files bigger than 512x512, because using a 64x64px icon for social media images and all the other things WP uses the site icon for would be bad for your site.

`.ico` files have limited support and capabilities, and have fundamental limitations on resolutions. They also have historic security issues.

You may want to upload a `.ico` file via CPanel for very old software but even if you do that, you should still include a PNG favicon via WP's site identity.

Note that there are tools and converters that can take an existing `.ico` file and transform it into a PNG file, so needing a PNG file should not be a problem, even if the only file you have is in the `.ico` format.

Comment: upscaling to a good looking PNG is not so easy... or do you have reliable tools? (in my case converting to a bigger png blurred it, converting to svg made an 'e' out of an 'B', so this intermediate step failed too)

Comment: that depends enormously on the images expectations or even the age of the machine you're planning to use it on, perhaps a good question for the software recommendations stack. Keep in mind that some graphics just don't work that well when resized down, and there is more than one way to resize a graphic up and down, e.g. nearest pixel, bicubic, bilinear, etc etc. `.ico` files tend to look clear because they're raster images that are very small so they appear pixel perfect unresized. A 16x16 or 24x24 PNG will yield better results too

Answer (score 0):

This is for security reasons, though I thought ICO was allowed...
You will need to add that type in permissions. This would be done in functions.php of the theme that you are using, unless you're writing a plugin, in which case it would belong in that.

```
function add_custom_mime_types($mimes) {
    $mimes['ico'] = 'image/x-icon';
    return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'add_custom_mime_types');
```

If that doesn't work, something else is blocking it, because ICO should be allowed by default.

Comment: I note that I have seen ICO files that have encoded malware inside, so they can be a security risk. Of course, any file you allow to upload can be a security risk. If you want to allow ICO files, you can, but be careful to verify that the ICO file is actually an ICO file, and not one in name only.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem.  I just noticed that there is some text saying images must be "at least 512x512 pixels"  WTF!  Mine is 64x64 pixels.  Well screw you Wordpress, I'll just bypass this by uploading directly, which works. I hate nannyware like this that gets in the way of productivity.

Comment: They're at least 512x512 pixels so that they appear clearly on devices. That's not nannyware.

Comment: @esotechnica the site identity is not just used for favicons, it can appear in the theme header as content, on social media previews, on smart phone home screens, lots of places that an `ico` file could never be used, where using less than 512px would actually be quite harmful for your site ( e.g. facebook previews ), or where a 64x64px graphic would be outright rejected.